# simple link to div id making main wrapper jump

Tags: jquery, css

so I am using simple links to div id on a few pages.

```
<a href="#mydiv">my link</div>
```

see - [current site](http://camandbenny.com/us)

The problem is that their is a mysterious shift in the main-wrapper when I click these links.  BUT - only when the browser is less than 800 tall.  I am stumped.

[image: Works a this size.]

[image: Then change to less than 800 high-]

[image: Then it just jumps for some reason.]

If you drag the browser down small it will go into smart phone style... and eveything is working there...

Any help would be super !!!

Comment: This is normal behaviour of how #-links work. And also: it's the same on mobile if the screen height is lower than content height. Maybe you should not use #links.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/vL6Xn/   I just made this fiddle and it happens here too.  @ Miszy --- do you know of any other options that would suit this need ?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, this is **normal behaviour of #links**. Once clicked, the page is scrolled so that referred element is in its top. There's no apparent solution to your problem using `CSS` only.

You could either divide the page into separate files (to avoid using #links) or use JavaScript to `preventDefault` beahaviour. I'll dive into the code for the later solution. Forgive me using jQuery, but it's much faster here.

So, the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vL6Xn/3/

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function () {
    var sel = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        if ($(sel).length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $cont = $(sel).parent().parent();
            var scrollVal = $cont.scrollTop() + $(sel).position().top;
            $cont.scrollTop(scrollVal);
        }
    });
});
```

What it does is:

1. Select `a` elements which have attribute `href` starting with #
2. Bind action on click: Try to select element referred in the `href` attribute and if it exists...
3. ...prevent default behaviour and scroll to proper position.

#### EDIT:

In your case scroll is applied to the parent of the parent of the element. I wrongly assumed it's jut parent. See my code update.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make that fiddle.  I am using wordpress, so I pass the $ like this //jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

Comment: But still no deal... it clearly shows the link in the bar at the bottom... ?  I am using an "anything slider" which uses hash-tags.  Do you think that is conflicting ?

Comment: The links will be visible, but this piece of code should override the default behaviour when they are clicked. Did you add this snippet to your website?

Comment: I added it locally - I'll put it up live now.  I just called the scripts conditionally for your code and anything slider so they wouldn't conflict - but still no luck... uploading now...

Comment: It is up there now.  It seems like everything is in place...  weird !

Comment: it works on a few links - but not others - and some links go to random places.

Comment: It works in the fiddle, so the principle is right. Try to improve the code according to your site's html.

Comment: I just found a little error in my code... one space   .jpg_""alt"  --- now it is working !!!  thank you so much for your time !!!

Comment: When I woke up this morning - It was acting all crazy again.  Some links work and some don't.  http://camandbenny.com/us/  (if you have it in you... )